Excel Problems Formatting Cells Based On Specific Input in Other Column
I am trying to format my 'A' column to change cell colour depending on the value in 'E'.
I can get it to work for a once off - but cant have it for multiple options across multiple cells.
Hoping these images will provide more information on what I am trying to achieve

I just want to change the A:'x' cell colour to match the same as E:'x' cell color depending on the value input.
Any excel gurus who can point out my fatal flaw ? :P
Thanks!
I tried just changing the rule to only select A2 & E2 - but when I used the drag down feature it only updated depending on E2 entry still rather than the subsequent cells in the column.


Just look at your conditional formatting formula in your own screenshot.  You are applying it only to cell =$A$2.  Simply change it to =$A:$A and it's going to work.

With cell A2 selected enter the formula as though you wanted it to work just for that row - keeping the row part of the formula relative rather than absolute.
Then apply that to your range.
In the image below I've applied it to just the range with data.  Note the formula still refers to $E2.

If I apply it to the whole row the formula updates to refer to cell $E1.

So with cell A2 selected I use the formula =$E2="BREAKDOWN" and in the Applies to box I use =$A:$A,$E:$E so it applies to columns A and E.


Since you're using custom number formatting, you may need to duplicate the rules when applying to column A.

While entering the whole columns ($A:$A) is convenient, it may lead to slowdown; if it happens change the range to a large enough one, such as $A1:$A2000
Having ISBLANK($E1) with no formatting and Stop if True checked as the first rule may improve performance
To use the rules you already have,

With E1 selected,
Conditional Formatting > "Show formatting rules for" > This Worksheet
Add the rule for ISBLANK at the top
For each of the existing rules with custom number formatting

select "Use a formula to select which cells to format"
enter the formula matching the value, such as $E1="B"
set Applies to $E:$E
duplicate this rule and move it above
set the number format to General
set Applies to $A:$A
For the rule with custom number formatting (for column E), check "Stop if True"





Hope this helps.

The screenshot shows the rules with E1 being the active cell:

